# Массивы и индексы

Tags: алгоритм, pascal

Как получить значения из двух массивов по одному индексу?.
Допустим есть 2 списка.
a:=[10,9];;b:=[8,7];;
нужно получить разбиения 10 по 8 и 9 по 7 слагаемых.

```
gap> f2:=function(n)
> local a,b,i,j,s1,s;
> a:=[10,9];b:=[8,7];s1:=[];
> for i in a do   
>   for j in b do
>       if j=i then a[i]:=i;b[i]:=j;fi;s:=Partitions(i,j);Add(s1,s);od;od;return(s1);
> end;
```

Comment: Что-что нужно сделать?

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.